# Django - Mixin with TemplateView

Tags: django, mixins, django-generic-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to do something like the following to work, but I keep receiving the error `'RegionsView' object has no attribute 'method'`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
#views.py

class _LanguageMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.langcode = kwargs.pop("langcode")
        self.language = get_object_or_404(Language, pk=self.langcode)
        return super(_LanguageMixin, self).dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(_LanguageMixin, self).get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
        context.update({"language": self.language,
                        "languages": Language.objects.values_list('code',
                                                                  flat=True)})
        return context


class RegionsView(_LanguageMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "regions.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RegionsView, self).get_context_data(self, **kwargs)

        regions = #......

        context.update({"regions": regions})
        return context


#urls.py

url(r'^(?P<langcode>[a-zA-Z-]+)/regions/$', RegionsView.as_view(), name='regions')
```

Comment: What is the exact stacktrace?

Comment: sorry, it is `RegionsView`

Comment: This line produces the error:`return super(_LanguageMixin, self).dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return super(_LanguageMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

instead of

```
return super(_LanguageMixin, self).dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

(`request.method` is used in the `dispatch` function, but you use `self` object)

Comment: seems it fiex my error, But now I got `get_context_data() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` at this line: `context = super(ThemesView, self).get_context_data(self, **kwargs)`

Comment: ``get_context_data`` must be used without ``self`` also

Comment: yep, removing `self` in both the calls seems to work. Thanks!